# Changing cluster size of SD card formatted as exFAT from 128KiB to some lower value?

Tags: sd-card, formatting

I'm using an app that allows me to download data for offline usage. The app is setup to store the data on my 64GB SD card. This all works fine, however, when I downloaded a larger set of data, i.e. some 6GB of data, that data used up some 30GB of storage space, and filled the SD card. I was baffled in the first place, so I had a deeper look at the data.

It turned out that the data consisted of some 120'000 files of 40KB in size, some larger, some smaller. I next had a look at the SD card and found it was formatted as exFAT and to use 128KiB blocksize (FX tells me so, I guess this should read cluster size).

I'm thinking about reformatting the SD card to use a smaller cluster size, say 48KiB or 64KiB, which would be more suitable for this kind of data.

Can this be done? Any inhibitors?

Comment: What is the filesystem used on the SD card? Put it in a Windows PC, right click on the drive in Explorer and select Format... There you can set the Allocation Unit Size, the options available vary with filesystem type used, but with exFat 32KB to 64KB is common default for that size, but you can manually set it as low as 2KB. Note that the more you reduce the Allocation Unit Size the more R/W performance will suffer.

Comment: I have updated the Q and added the filesystem type (exFAT). Sorry, I missed to write that since FX app already told me.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the cluster size in the meantime. Copied everything from the SD card to my Windows machine, then used Windows' Explorer context menu "Format" to reformat the SD card.

A big part of the 200'000+ files I need to add are smaller than 32KiB, another large chunk is between 32KiB and 48KiB, so I chose 32KiB as cluster size. (48KiB would have been a better choice but this is not supported for cluster size)

Copied everything back to the SD card, and was able to store the full 6GiB set of those small files. They now occupy only some 10GiB compared to 30GiB not having been enough before reformatting.

I haven't seen any negative impact of this change so far, but is is only a day since.